# Trouble switching my default display in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have MainWindow.xib file which holds a SplitViewController.

After some re-organising of the application flow, we now want to open with a different screen.
I've added a new ViewController to the xib and removed SplitViewController, I then changed this new ViewController's class to HomeViewController (which has been set up).

I my AppDelegate, I removed all reference to SplitViewController and swapped it for HomeViewController. So, in theory, it should work by now bringing up the HomeViewController instead of the SplitViewController.

I get this crash:

```
[<UIApplication 0x7f433b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.
```

I'm not sure where this error is occurring - have I missed a step in what I should have done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've accidentally connected a view to your application instance rather than your view controller. Since `UIApplication` has no `view` property, this throws an error when the nib file is loaded. Remove that connection and you should be fine.

Comment: In my MainWindow nib, HomeViewController's view outlet is empty and that appears to be the only reference to view in the whole Nib. Obviously, I dragged the view controller the objects in IB, so there's no attached view, just a reference to the View Controller. In my HomeViewController nib, the view is connected as to be expected to the primary view of that VC

Comment: If it's not trouble perhaps you should just recreate your nib file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was a stupid mistake I made earlier that complicated things. Before I tried this approach, I tried to swap the main nib line in the -info.plist to a different nib. I hadn't returned it to MainWindow for this approach.